# How to check for null values and replace it if the object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want the null values to be removed and the tempVal1 to be updated.
The removal is in the arrays where id date id null, the full data in the array at that index will be deleted.

Thank you in advance

```
//tempVal1 received from an API
    const tempVal1 = {
      user_id: 'emp_1',
      account_id: 'random1',
      emp_name: 'John Doe',
      projects_name: [
        {name: 'project 1', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
        {name: 'project 2', date: ''},
        {name: 'project 3', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
        {name: 'project 4', date: ''},
      ],
      manager: 'stella',
      companies_worked_at: [
        {name: 'company 1', date: ''},
        {name: 'company 2', date: ''},
        {name: 'company 3', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
        {name: 'company 1', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
      ],
      devices: [
        {name: 'device 1', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
        {name: 'device 2', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
        {name: 'device 3', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
        {name: 'device 4', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
        {name: 'device 6', date: ''},
        {name: 'device 5', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
      ],
      emp_wife: 'Jane Doe',
      places_visited: [
        {name: 'place 1', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
        {name: 'place 2', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
        {name: 'place 3', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
      ],
      team_mates: [{name: '', date: ''}],
      present_status: 'Working',
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this, might help:

```js
const obj = {
      user_id: 'emp_1',
      account_id: 'random1',
      emp_name: 'John Doe',
      projects_name: [
        {name: 'project 1', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
        {name: 'project 2', date: ''},
        {name: 'project 3', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
        {name: 'project 4', date: ''},
      ],
      manager: 'stella',
      companies_worked_at: [
        {name: 'company 1', date: ''},
        {name: 'company 2', date: ''},
        {name: 'company 3', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
        {name: 'company 1', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
      ],
      devices: [
        {name: 'device 1', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
        {name: 'device 2', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
        {name: 'device 3', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
        {name: 'device 4', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
        {name: 'device 6', date: ''},
        {name: 'device 5', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
      ],
      emp_wife: 'Jane Doe',
      places_visited: [
        {name: 'place 1', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
        {name: 'place 2', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
        {name: 'place 3', date: '2021-08-10T15:40:00+00:00'},
      ],
      team_mates: [{name: '', date: ''}],
      present_status: 'Working',
    };

// This is the piece of code you need
Object.keys(obj).forEach(e => Array.isArray(obj[e]) && (obj[e] = obj[e].filter(e => e.date)));
```

This will go through every key in the object and if the value is an array then filter those elements in it that doesn't have a valid date (not null, undefined, ...)

Answer (score -1):

You can collect the keys which are of arrays. Then [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the elements  only if the dates are not null. Once it does, we need to restore it to the original object.

```
> tempVal1
   {user_id: "emp_1", account_id: "random1", emp_name: "John Doe".....}

> keys= ["projects_name", "companies_worked_at", "devices", "places_visited"]

> keys.map(ele => {
    tempVal1[ele]= tempVal1[ele].filter(ele => ele.date);
   })
```

[image: output image]

Another way is to collect the object keys which are of type arrays and do the filter on it.

```js
Object.keys(tempVal1).map(ele => {
if (Array.isArray(tempVal1[ele])){
    tempVal1[ele]= tempVal1[ele].filter(subEle => subEle.date)
}
})
```

You can check the functions [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: A dump of code with no explanation followed by a picture does not rise to the level of "useful"

Comment: @HereticMonkey, Agreed. Added the explanation..Thanks :)